# Import Local module over global python

Tags: python, import, python-2.7

I have a 2 python files. One is trying to import the second. My problem is that the second is named math.py. I can not rename it. When I attempt to call a function that is located inside math.py, I can not because I end up with the global math module. How would I import my local file instead of the global. I am using Python 2.7, and this is(roughly) my import statment:

```
cstr = "math"
command = __import__(cstr)
```

Later I try:

```
command.in_math_py_not_global()
```

**Edit:** a more complete example:

```
def parse(self,string):
    clist = string.split(" ")
    cstr= clist[0]
    args = clist[1:len(clist)]
    rvals = []
    try:
        command = __import__(cstr)
        try:
            rvals.extend(command.main(args))
        except:
            print sys.exc_info()
    except ImportError:
        print "Command not valid"
```

Comment: I just tried creating a `test.py` with `import math`, and a `math.py` in the same directory, and it worked fine. I could call `math.foo()` in my own `math.py` with no problem.

Comment: I get AttributeError("'module' object has no attribute 'main'",)

Comment: Can you provide a small, complete example that shows exactly what you are doing to cause that error?

Comment: There, I am basicly letting the user input a string, with the first word of that string used as a command. The command is passed on to a module named after the command. In this case I have math with a file called math.py.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python processes have a single namespace of loaded modules. If you (or *any other module*) has already loaded the standard `math` module for any reason, then trying to load it again with `import` or `__import__()` will simply return a reference to the already-loaded module. You should be able to verify this using `print id(math)` and comparing with `print id(command)`.

Although you've stated that you are unable to change the name of `math.py`, I suggest you can. You are getting the name of the module to load from the user. You can modify this before actually using the `__import__()` function to add a prefix. For example:

```
command = __import__("cmd_" + cstr)
```

Then, rename `math.py` to `cmd_math.py` and you will avoid this conflict.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try your second suggestion. The first did not work, I got a name error saying math is not defined.

Answer (score 3):

You could use relative imports:

```
from . import math
```

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references

Comment: Thats not good enough for what I need. In any case I have tried that and only gotten package errors.