# Python import issues, can't find module

Tags: python

From all I've read at https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html, the *main.py* code should work. I can't for the life of me figure out why it doesn't work.

**Versions etc.**

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-precise-64:/vagrant/monkey$ python --version
Python 2.7.3
```

**Directory Structure**

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-precise-64:/vagrant/monkey$ ll
total 6
drwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant    0 Jul 30 07:18 ./
drwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant 4096 Jul 30 07:04 ../
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant   76 Jul 30 07:09 abc.py*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant   76 Jul 30 07:10 bcd.py*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant   43 Jul 30 06:56 main.py*
```

**abc.py**

```
# abc module


def bar():
    print 'abc.bar called.'
    return None
```

**bcd.py**

```
# bcd module


def foo():
    print 'bcd.foo called.'
    return None
```

**main.py**

```
import abc
import bcd


abc.bar()
bcd.foo()
```

**Error**

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-precise-64:/vagrant/monkey$ python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
    abc.bar()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'bar'
```

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`abc` is a builtin Python module](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/abc.html). Rename your `abc.py` to something else.

Answer (score 1):

nothing wrong with your code. But abc is a builtin module. Try to do a `locate abc.py`, and you should see lines like:

```
/usr/lib/python2.6/abc.py
/usr/lib/python2.6/abc.pyc
```

Either try to rename your module, or search SO for things like [Import Local module over global python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11489330/import-local-module-over-global-python)